# Progressbar without knowing the number of tasks

Tags: c#, .net

I have to execute a batch of tasks which depend on each other.
For example i have to unzip 2 files, which contain other files for further processing. But before i unzip them, i cant know how many files i have to deal with. And after further processing per file, i have to create new tasks depending on them etc.

Hence i can't bind to the progressbar value the total number of tasks before the execution starts.

How do you deal with that dynamic task scenario in your projects?

Comment: You can make a file count before processing the actual files. After performing the count you can go ahead and do with the files what you want. This is why most software has an 'analyze' or 'load' mode before performing tasks.

Comment: The typical thing in this case is to update the progress bar based on two values `x` & `y` - where `y` is the total number of items that you **compute as you go** and `x` is the number of items processed. You start with `x = 0` & `y = 1` - so you start with 0%, but as soon as you read the first zip file you can update `y`.

Answer (score 1):

Use a indeterminate progress bar or busy indicator. In WPF ProgressBar control, there is a property called IsIndeterminate.